# Composition of bounded and unbounded operator

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory

Let $\mathcal{A}$ be an unbounded operator and let $\mathcal{C}$ be a bounded operator. What we can say about the boundedness of the operator $\mathcal{C}\mathcal{A}$? I look for a textbook about the operator theory.

Comment: Looking at $\mathcal{C}=0$ and $\mathcal{C}=I$ shows that the composition $\mathcal{C}\mathcal{A}$ can be either bounded or not.

Answer (score 1):

You can have $C=0$ in this case $CA=0$ is bounded, or $C=I$, $CA=A$ is unbounded.

Comment: What if $C\neq 0$